# Word / PDF - Merge Documents

Tags: vba, ms-word, adobe

I am looking to merge two documents, however it is not your typical merge.

My first document is a mailmerge, creating a cover letter, basically each page has a name and address

My next document is a static document that cannot be changed.

I need to insert the static document into my first merged document, but after every page, therefore, for every one page a document is inserted.

I have tried the insert document in both word 2010 and pdf using adobe acrobat, and as you have thought it only inserted one document after the first page.

I'm looking at VBA, but I have never utilized VBA and word before

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I should have spent more time on this.

The original template contains fields to merge.

On the static document that I mention, click insert tab, Text Section, select Object - Text From File

Select the cover letter / template that contains the fields to merge.  This will insert the template followed by the static document that cannot be changed
**Note I have spotted some formatting changes on the template following merge - further work required**

From this point start your mail merge, and complete merge to Adobe or word.

This creates a mail merged document containing the cover letter with name and address fields followed by the static document.

Extremely simple.  I always over complicate things!

I'll work on the changed formatting, but other then that this works